# How to monitor desktop environment mouse event in gtk programming

Tags: gtk, mouse, monitor, global-hotkey

In GTK programming, how to monitor desktop environment mouse event while the GTK application is not active, i.e, the mouse is focus on other GTK application?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a library **keybinder** which is what I want!

The homepage(**http://kaizer.se/wiki/keybinder/**) of that library introduces that keybinder is a library for registering global keyboard shortcuts. Keybinder works with GTK-based applications using the X Window System.